# Find a substring in a line and print the line in python and only print the line once?

Tags: python, substring

I am trying to print all the lines in my text file that contain any of the words in my list, caled "names". The problem I am having is that my program iterates so much that, duplicate lines get printed because of the multiple iterations. How can I print the line occurance only once? Also how can I print the line(s) to an output file?

Here is what I have so far:

```
names=[bob,carter,jim,mike]
with open("base.txt") as openfile:
         for line in openfile:
             for part in line.split():
                 for i in names:
                     if i in part:

                         print line
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to split the lines, just check if the line as a whole contains the name. Also, no need to check for every name, the first match will do. [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) will help you avoid some bumpy code:

```
with open("base.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if any(name in line for name in names):
            print line
```

Comment: I think the if block is missing a ':'. Also the OP asks about writing to a file. If you add it your answer will be complete.

Comment: @SilentMonk Thx for attention. Updated!

Answer (score 0):

Check once for all names and use `any()` as follows.

```
names=['bob','carter','jim','mike']
with open("base.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if any([n in line for n in names]):
            print line.strip()
```

What `[n in line for n in names]` does is check for each name in the line and return a list of boolean. `any()` checks if any of the elements of list is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

As others already posted, you can use `any` to confirm the occurrence of at least one of the names in the line. Use a list comprehension to put all the matching lines into a list:

```
with open("base.txt") as openfile, open("output.txt", "w") as outputfile:
     result = [line if any(n in line for n in names) for line in openfile]
     outputfile.writelines(result) # wwii's comment: the lines already contain a separator
```

To write `result` to `outputfile`, you should use the `writelines` method which takes the `result` sequence as argument (@wwii's comment).

Comment: Shouldn't each line in result end in a line separator if there was a line separator in the original file?  If so ... ```outputfile.writelines(result)```

Comment: My bad. What was I thinking. Thanks